# why postman app unable to get any request for the update program written in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, findoneandupdate

I have used following update method to update record in mongodb using nodejs. I feel something wrong with route i have given in the URL.In place of studentEmail in the route, i have given existing studetEmail address of the database.

```
app.put("/update/:studentEmail",(req,res)=>{
    let upstudentEmail=req.params.studentEmail;
    let upstudentName=req.body.studentName;
    let upsection=req.body.section;
async function updatebyemail(studentEmail){
        
    try{
    //find and update
    const result= await studentInfomodel.findOneAndUpdate({studentEmail:upstudentEmail},{$set:{studentName:upstudentName,section:upsection}},
        {new:true});
        console.log(result);
            if(data==null){
               res.send("nothing found")
            }else{
               res.send(data)
            }
        }catch{
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
})
```